# Create a new Pandas column based on string matches in a JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df =
     SomeText
0    foo foo foo bar
1    bar foo buzz
2    bar bar bar
3    buzz buzz buzz buzzer
```

And a JSON:

```
json_dict =

{
    "text": [
        {
            "notes": [],
            "code": 1,
            "word": foo,
        },
        {
            "notes": [],
            "code": 2,
            "word": bar,
        },
        {
            "notes": [buzzer],
            "code": 3,
            "word": buzz,
        }
    ]
}
```

I'll like to parse over the text in the `SomeText` column and append a new column to `df` based on data stored in the JSON. If the word appears in the string, append the code. If the word also matches the notes, append the same code.

```
df =
     SomeText                Code
0    foo foo foo bar         1, 1, 1, 2
1    bar foo buzz            2, 1, 3
2    bar bar bar             2, 2, 2
3    buzz buzz buzz buzzer   3, 3, 3, 3
4    not in json             -
```

Words not contained within the JSON don't matter.

I've got some experience doing this between dataframes but not using JSON files as reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SomeText': {0: 'foo foo foo bar', 1: 'bar foo buzz', 2: 'bar bar bar', 3: 'buzz buzz buzz buzzer', 4: 'not in json  '}})
dct = {'text': [{'notes': [], 'code': 1, 'word': 'foo'}, {'notes': [], 'code': 2, 'word': 'bar'}, {'notes': ['buzzer'], 'code': 3, 'word': 'buzz'}]}
```

Create a dictionary that maps the words from your JSON to their values:

```
mapper = {i['word']: i['code'] for i in dct['text']}
# {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'buzz': 3}
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
df['Code'] = [[mapper[i] for i in t.split() if i in mapper] or '-' for t in df.SomeText]
```

Output:

```
                SomeText          Code
0        foo foo foo bar  [1, 1, 1, 2]
1           bar foo buzz     [2, 1, 3]
2            bar bar bar     [2, 2, 2]
3  buzz buzz buzz buzzer     [3, 3, 3]
4          not in json               -
```

To use the contents of `notes` as well, use a simple for loop to create the new dictionary:

```
mapper = {}
for i in dct['text']:
    mapper.update({j: i['code'] for j in i['notes']})
    mapper.update({i['word']: i['code']})

                SomeText          Code
0        foo foo foo bar  [1, 1, 1, 2]
1           bar foo buzz     [2, 1, 3]
2            bar bar bar     [2, 2, 2]
3  buzz buzz buzz buzzer  [3, 3, 3, 3]
4          not in json               -
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. Any idea how you would add in the 'notes' section within the JSON as well? Such as for index 3 in the second df (Code = [3, 3, 3, 3])?

Comment: @DanielBourke I updated my answer to show how to use the contents of `notes` as well.  If this helped you out, please consider accepting the answer!